# Social Media buttons inside hidden Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Has anybody been able to get the Facebook Like, Twitter Follow, and Google +1 buttons to work inside a chrome extension.

I can get the buttons to show up, and some functionality, but seem to be missing parts.  For instance the Like button doesn't remember if you liked it, it shows the count of 1 every time.  Twitter doesn't show the correct number of followers, and is missing the @username after the "Follow" text.

I know the extensions are sandboxed.  Has anybody found a way around this?  Example?  Code?

**UPDATE**

The problem is that the social media buttons are inside a div that is hidden (display: none).  The div uses jQuery's slideToggle to show and hide.  By default the div is not showing and the social media buttons are on it.  When I put the social media buttons in a div that is not hidden they work fine.  Any solutions?

The problem was that the social media buttons are inside a hidden div (a different display that can be accessed through a tab).  Is there any way to make them work without update the z-index on triggered events?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved.  I added the markup to the markup page and made an anonymous function call to the API script immediately after the slideToggle began.  Works perfect.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. The Facebook buttons are located on a div that is set to display:none; (until a hover action). Having trouble getting the anonymous funciton call to work. Can you share the code you used?

Comment: @Mark1270287 I ended up scrapping the social media buttons so I don't have the code anymore - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

They do work in an extension page. You have to explicitly specify a public URL and facebook/twitter have to be modified to explicitly include the protocol. `//platform.twitter.com` to `https://platform.twitter.com`

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @twitter</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=113869198637480";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="250" data-show-faces="false"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
  <g:plusone href='http://example.com'></g:plusone>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I have already done this before even posting this question.  Doing this makes the the buttons work in the way mentioned above. However I want them fully functional.

Comment: For instance, the twitter button says "Follow" but not "Follow @jjNford"

Comment: I am thinking the problem is Twitter and Facebook are attempting to contact the button, but it does not have a URL that can be reached because it is sandboxed.

Comment: The code in my answer shows `Follow @twitter` for me. Each button remembers state as expected as well.

Comment: hmmmm... that is very strange... I have no idea why mine is not working then.  Are you setting any permissions in your manifest?

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your code... didn't work for me.  Same results I have been getting.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using and are you using `manifest_version: 2`?

Comment: Fixed it, my code was working, The div I was placing it in is hidden to the extension first loads (its actually on a different tab).  Do you know anyway around this issue?

Comment: what do you mean "on a different tab"?

Comment: Within the extension there are multiple tabs a user can navigate through.  The social media buttons are on a dedicated tab that is not showing when the extension loads.

Comment: HTML tabs that are switched using JavaScript? Can you update your question with a http://jsfiddle.net/ example that demos the behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: Was trying to generalize.  Okay I have the social media buttons inside a div element that is hidden (display: none).  The a button is pressed jQuery slides the div down (slideToggle) that the social media buttons are in.