# Load Twitter Follow button inside hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, social-networking

I've basically run into the same issue as this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662576/social-media-buttons-inside-hidden-div) but as the poster scrapped the code before sharing I was hoping someone would have a solution.

I'm loading a set of social media icons in a hidden div, which become visible when hovered. The issue seems to be that as the Follow button is loaded in a hidden div, it doesn't append the @username but simply displays "Follow".

Any help would be highly appreciated!

This should reproduce the issue for you;

HTML:

```
<li><a class="menu">Menu Item</a>
<ul id="blah-menu">
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-dnt="true">Follow @twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
nav li ul#blah-menu {
display: none;
z-index: 99999 !important;
}

nav li:hover ul#blah-menu {
display: block;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Provide some sample code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Added sample code, see edit

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMrUP/) that shows the problem

Comment: Well that wasn't the solution, rather code that would generate the problem for others to see.

Comment: Ha my bad, didn't read that properly

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but it appears this person has this hidden but maybe it will [http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/ErFGv](http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/ErFGv)...I looked at it a bit yesterday and it was weird for sure

Comment: The Follow button in the link you provided is not actually in a div which is set to display:none, so unfortunately not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up showing 1x1 (and overflow:hidden) div wrapper with twitter button code somewhere in the footer and then when the button is supposed to be shown, just move the wrapper to the desired position and set overflow:visible

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I soved it using setinterval.

```
var twitterListener = setInterval(function(){
  if(jQuery("#yourDiv").is(":visible")){
    clearInterval(twitterListener)
    if (typeof window.twttr == "undefined") {
      window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
          var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
          js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
      }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    }

    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('click', function (event) { 
          //
        });
        twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
            //
        });
        twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
            //
        });        
    }); 
  }
},10)
```